# extract value from sql json in logic apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

In logic app , I  have a for each loop which extract the SQL rows.
I want my output - SP1'b506-1b205db6dcd3'.

Write now I am able to get - "value": "{"NAME":"SP1"}'b506-1b205db6dcd3'".

How can I get value of Name from the above SQL output - SP1 only?

```
  "For_each": {
    "actions": {
      "Append_to_array_variable": {
        "inputs": {
          "name": "sp_name",
          "value": "@concat(items('For_each'),'''',outputs('Compose'),'''')"
        },
        "runAfter": {},
        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
      }
  }
```

Right now output is following

```
    {
        "name": "sp_name",
        "value": "{\"NAME\":\"SP1\"}'b506-1b205db6dcd3'"
    }
```

I want value - SP1 from @concat(items('For_each') to concat with another variable.

Comment: Show the output in a screenshot that we have to deal with because as of right now, it's hard to understand which value you want to parse.

Comment: You also need to show the `compose` step because it's clearly important.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that there was 'Resultsets Name' as output of the execute sql query which is providing me that value.Regards.

Answer (score 0):

> Write now I am able to get - "value": "{"NAME":"SP1"}'b506-1b205db6dcd3'".

Considering "value": "{"NAME":"SP1"}'b506-1b205db6dcd3'" you can use slice() just to retrieve the value {"NAME":"SP1"} using the below expression.

```
slice(variables('var'),nthIndexOf(variables('var'),'{',2),add(nthIndexOf(variables('var'),'}',1),1))
```

and then we can use `Parse JSON` for that particular expression and pull out the `NAME` value "SP1". Here is the flow of my logic app

[image]

**RESULTS:**

[image]